# Hide or Disable UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am presenting a UIViewController with a Modal Segue.
This UIViewController inherits a UINavigationBar and I have set a UIBarButtonItem on the left side of the Navigation Bar:

[image: HELP ME!!!]

My problem is that when the viewWillAppear method of the presented UIViewController is called, I'm trying to hide the UIBarButtonItem, but the UIBarButtonItem always appears.
I've declared a UIBarButtonItem for the UIViewController, named myCancelButton, and I've referenced it in Interface Builder.

Here's what I've tried so far (all of which does not work):

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.myCancelButton = nil;

    NSMutableArray *barButtonItems = [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems mutableCopy];
    [barButtonItems removeObject:self.myCancelButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = barButtonItems;

    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems delete:self.myCancelButton];

    self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    barButtonItems = [self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems mutableCopy];
    [barButtonItems removeObject:self.myCancelButton];
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = barButtonItems;

    [self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems delete:self.myCancelButton];

    [self.myCancelButton setWidth:0.01];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;

    //Even setting enabled to false doesn't work:
    [self.myCancelButton setEnabled:FALSE];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Comment: I have already tried these in my original post:

    self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;

Comment: Just wait i'm little busy.If i'll free than i'll read this one .

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to find a solution to this?